# How to get the specific name of an element based on attribute position in the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this code to get the specific name of each classes inside an element  based on their attribute position inside Class attribute list

For example if I want to get the second class inside the div name

This code is returning all class names

```
 var SecondclassName = $(this).attr('class');
```

but I need to get only the second one!

```js
$("#banner-message").on('click', function(){
  var FirstclassName = $(this).attr('class');
  // var SecondclassName = $(this).attr('class');
  // var ThirdclassName = $(this).attr('class');
  console.log(FirstclassName);
});
```

```css
#banner-message {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cl1 cl2 cl3" id="banner-message"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has a built-in property on all elements `classList` - since you want the second one, use `[1]`. Use destructuring to get all three:

```js
$("#banner-message").on('click', function(){
  var [FirstclassName, SecondclassName, ThirdclassName] = this.classList;
  console.log(FirstclassName);
  console.log(SecondclassName);
  console.log(ThirdclassName);
  var second = this.classList[1];
  console.log(second);
});
```

```css
#banner-message {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cl1 cl2 cl3" id="banner-message"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a DOMTokenList, which is an array like construct, on the Element that holds all the classes.

```js
$("#banner-message").on('click', function(){
  console.log(this.classList[1]);
});
```

```css
#banner-message {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cl1 cl2 cl3" id="banner-message"></div>
```

Comment: This is the vanilla way, but there isn't a need to have a jQuery way.  Afaik, this works in all browsers.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=classList  support for classList has been around for a long time.  You'd have to be in a very old browser for it not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also split the result you get with `attr()` and address each element by it's index like this:

```
$("#banner-message").on('click', function(){
  var array = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  var FirstclassName = array[0]
  // var SecondclassName = array[1];
  // var ThirdclassName = array[2];
  console.log(FirstclassName);
});
```

but it is advisable to use `classList` as it already provides you with the array

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the classList property which returns the class name(s) of an element.

```
<div id="myDiv" class="first second third">
</div>

console.log(document.getElementById("myDiv").classList[1]);
```

will return "second".